# Images acting weird on specific mobile phone

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I recently developed a responsive website. I had no problems all checks are fine and on all mobile phones I have seen it works fine. My customer came to me and said that the website looks weird on her mobile phone (she has a Jiayu type JY-G4S, Android 4.2.2.). So she send a screenshot:

[image]

How it is supposed to be (and how I see it everywhere):
[image]

The arrows are SVG files and are added like this:

```
<div class="white-up">
    <img src="/path/to/WHITE_SHAPE_UP.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

The compiled css (from Sass):

```
.white-up {
    bottom: -9px;
}
.arrows, .white-up {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
arrows img, .white-up img {
    height: auto;
    left: -1%;
    width: 102%;
}
```

I can't seem to find the problem with the website. Do any of you have experience with such issues on a specific phone and have tips on how to debug this?

I am stuck at the moment so any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

PS. The link to the live website is http://pleun.photo

Comment: This is not a Sass or PHP problem:  only post the compiled CSS/HTML

Comment: Changed the PHP and Sass to the compiled CSS/HTML as you suggested